# Has anyone automated an app built in RSA Archer?

Tags: automated-testing, tools

I'm looking for tool options to develop regression and production validation scripts for a few apps built in the RSA Archer eGRC suite.  I have not been able to find much information available out there.

Has anyone attempted or had success automating Archer?

Comment: There is a company called Allied Media (https://alliedmedia.com) they have an orchestration tool for Archer.